# GNU/Libtool cross-compilation

Tags: shared-libraries, gnu, cross-compiling, autotools, libtool

I have very base question about `GNU/Libtool`. My project is build by `GNU/autotools` and contains the shared object build by `GNU/Libtool`. I want to compile the `i386` shared object on the `x86-64` machine, so I do:

```
$ ./configure --build=i386
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
...
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
...
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
$
```

The configure script tell me the the shared libraries are not supported, and the `make` command fails. How to fix this cross-compile issue?

Should I find the answer in [Libtool manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--build` is typically for things like [Canadian cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#Canadian_Cross) compilation. You probably want to use the `--host` option. You haven't specified the system type, but if `./config.guess` gives something like:

`x86_64-apple-darwin` or `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

Then you would specifiy

`--host=i386-apple-darwin` or `i386-pc-linux-gnu`

Also - you may need to set some compiler flags to force 32-bit code generation. e.g.,

`env CC="gcc -m32" ./configure --host=....`

Often, the `-m32` option is sufficient - you won't need to bother with the `--host` option.

Comment: Have added `-m32` flags to compiler and linker to force 32-bit code generation